# Title not changing | Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to override the document title on a route.
This is the route with a default title.

```
{
  path: 'artikel/:id/:slug',
  component: ArticleComponent,
  data: {title: 'Article', routeType: RouteType.ARTICLE, 
  description: metaDescription},
  resolve: {error: ErrorResolverService, article: ArticleResolveService},
}
```

I am using an ArticleResolverService to get the article from the ID and then apply a new Title.

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<Article> {
    let id = route.paramMap.get('id');
    return this.as.getArticle(id).take(1).map(article => {
        if (article) {
            //this seems to set the title temporarely (flickering visible)
            this.ts.setTitle(article.title);
            return article;
        }
        return null;
    });
}
```

Since this approach doesn't quite work I tried setting the title in the ArticleComponent, which is the target of the route. (This happens in `ngOnInit`)

```
this.route.data.subscribe((data:{article: Article}) => {
    this.article = data.article;

    //this seems to set the title temporarely (flickering visible)
    this.ts.setTitle(this.article.title);

    //using this in browser console works permanently
    window['setTitle'] = (t) => this.ts.setTitle(t);
});
```

Whatever I am doing, everytime I load the page i see the flickering of the wanted title but then it gets instantly reset to the default title (if I don't use a default title it will just show the page URL in the title bar, also just after flickering of the wanted title).

How do i effectively set a permanent title for this page?

Answer (score -2):

The last step from your question is not required (`window['setTitle']`). Works just fine with the approach below. The default title will show until the `setTitle` function is called, then it will stay at the new title

Import Title service

```
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

Inject it

```
constructor(
...
private titleService: Title,
) {...}
```

Use it in the ngOnInit

```
this.titleService.setTitle("Some custom title" + this.newInfoFromAPI);
```

Comment: That is how it is supposed to be yes. But it doesn't stay! It just flickers for a sec then gets replaced by the default title. That is the whole root of my problem. The thing with the window was just for testing ;)

Comment: I think {
  path: 'artikel/:id/:slug',
  component: ArticleComponent,
  data: {title: 'Article', routeType: RouteType.ARTICLE, 
  description: metaDescription},
  resolve: {error: ErrorResolverService, article: ArticleResolveService},
} is overwriting the setTitle function. Try removing the line data: {title: 'Article', routeType: RouteType.ARTICLE,..

Comment: As stated in my question, I tried that already, it just takes the URL instead